# Logging multiple threads with nlog

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, nlog

I use nlog logger in my project.

My program generates xml files based on data which i getting from sql server. I'm doing this with PLINQ. But also i have to log tracing info to be able make some investigations on exceptional cases on prod environment.

Result logs looks awful, when it came from multiple threads. For example:

```
Operation 1 started
Deserializing XXX
Operation 2 started
Deserializing XXX finished with status X
Filling XXX with data from Z
Deserializing YYY....
```

And its just for degree of parallelism 2.

I'd like to see result like this:

```
Operation 1 started
Deserializing XXX
Deserializing XXX finished with status X
Filling XXX with data from Z
Operation 1 finished
Operation 2 started    
Deserializing YYY....
```

I see some solutions, but they're not looking good enough:

1. Save logging data to some buffer and flush it when parallel task ends - I will be ought to pass context to all inner methods (looks terrible!).
2. Add some kind of prefix to logging message to help getting context for some messages - i have to pass prefix to every inner message (also looks terrible).

Is there some clean solutions for this problem?

Comment: I think that logging in the actual order of events may actually be valuable for error detection, because a typical error in a multithreaded environment is, of course, some unanticipated order of events. But why not prefix the log messages with a thread name/ID? Logging could be channeled through an interface in the thread (which is a good idea anyway) which could add the prefix to the actual message. That way you can always post-process your logs to see all messages related to a particular thread together.

Comment: And I think buffering is a doubtful strategy for logging, because the events that lead to a catastrophic error may never be written to the log.

Comment: Can you push all of the log writing to a concurrent queue and then dequeue off on a different thread?

Comment: Its independent xml filling process - so i dont have to save ordering in that particular case. But it have very complex domain logic - so i have to save order in particular thread, because investigation by pile of logs from many different threads will be nightmare for me. Yes, i can use ThreadId, but I'll have to use some filtering with grouping and ordering btw

Comment: @Enigmativity it looks interesting, could you describe it with more detail, please?

Comment: @Mitklantekutli - I looked at the forums and it appears that it supports it out of the box - http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Multi-Threading-in-NLog-td3728834.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In NLog config files, there is the `${threadid}` syntax. Use it like this:

```xml
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
     layout="${longdate} [${threadid}] ${level:uppercase=true} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
     fileName="${basedir}/logs/log.txt"
     archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/log.{#####}.txt"
     archiveAboveSize="10485760"
     archiveNumbering="Sequence"
     concurrentWrites="true"
     keepFileOpen="false" />
```

More info:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ThreadId-Layout-Renderer

I used it in production and generally it works. It is not perfect, but all operations (which I logged) is in sequence and this `threadid` describe which operation is in which ThreadId.

Comment: Its simple and clean solution, but it needs to add some filtering and ordering tools. Lots of mixed with ids cant help without additional text processing. I'm considering this variant as reserved :)

Comment: You want to create a nice viewer to log file? It is other layer and it is lot of tool to do this.

Comment: My question was about avoiding it.

Comment: The threadid is of type int, for those who are wondering. https://github.com/jpdillingham/NLog.RealtimeLogger